# How to create onclick event for input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I created an input field and I want some event to be fired on click of the input field.

For that, I am using `onClick` method but my debugger is not going to `TableExpand()` function. Even in input tag also I am not able to see `onClick` event.

Here is my code.

```
MyData = function(args) {
    debugger;
    var dataUrl = args.url;
    var divID = args.divID;
    var div = document.getElementById(divID); 

    var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.className = 'styled-select';
        input.style = 'width:30%' ;
        input.id = "SearchInput";
        input.type = "text";
        input.title = "Madd";
        input.onclick = "TableExpand()"; // This is not adding in input tag.

        div.appendChild(input);

        //input.onkeyup = "TableExpand()";
        //input.addEventListener('click', 'TableExpand()');

        //div.onclick

TableExpand = function(){
    debugger;

}
}
```

Can anybody please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The value assigned to the `onclick` property needs to be a **function**.

You are assigning a *string*.

```
input.onclick = TableExpand;
```

… you also need to define `TableExpand` **before** you try to use it.

Using a function declaration instead of a function expression will suffice for that (as declarations are hoisted).

```
function TableExpand (){
    debugger;
}
```

Comment: Mean `TableExpand ` function I need to use before `MyData` ?

Comment: No. Before `input.onclick = TableExpand;` (alternatively, do what I already said in the answer.)